# How to create a Silverlight control that has two content areas

Tags: silverlight

I want to create a Silverlight 2 control that has two content areas.  A Title and a MainContent.  So the control would be:

```
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text=" CONTENT1 "/>
<Content with CONTENT2 "/>
</StackPanel>
```

When I use the control I should just be able to use:

```
<MyControl Text="somecontent">main content </MyControl>
```

How can I create such a control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that easily with the [ContentProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx) attribute.

Then you can define your code behind as:

```
[ContentProperty("Child")]
public partial class MyControl: UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Child", typeof(UIElement), typeof(MyControl), null);

    public UIElement Child
    {
        get { return (UIElement)this.GetValue(ChildProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ChildProperty, value);
            this.content.Content = value;
        }
    }
```

What that will do is any default content within your tags (`<MyControl Text="somecontent">main content </MyControl>`) - will be set as the Child property on your class. Then once it's been set you can assign it to any control you like.

**Edit:**

You can have as many contents as you like, but you can only have 1 auto-content (which is designated via the ContentProperty attribute).
If you want two you could do:

```
<MyControl>
  <MyControl.Content1>Hello World</MyControl.Content1>
  <MyControl.Content2>Goodbye World</MyControl.Content2>
</MyControl>
```

All you have to do is make sure you have the matching dependency properties in your code. Then when the property is set, just assign it to a parent content control in your XAML.

Comment: Perfect, can I have two contents?

Comment: Answered in my question as I didn't have enough characters here.

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted is a Silverlight version of the WPF HeaderedContentControl
You can find a try here. http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/headeredcontentcontrol-sample/